# Reemplazar un campo de un registro en específico en un array - PHP

Tags: php, date, fpdf

Tengo un array lleno de registros, pero quiero buscar si en ese array existe un cliente y reemplazar un campo de ese cliente, pero no sé cómo realizarlos.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
while ($clid=$sqlc->fetch_assoc()) {
  if (!in_array($clid["cliente"], $arrayName)) {
    $datos = array(
      Cliente => $clid["cliente"], Nombre => $clid["nombre"],
      Jan => $val, Feb => $val, Mar => $val, Apr => $val,
      May => $val, Jun => $val, Jul => $val, Aug => $val,
      Sep => $val, Oct => $val, Nov => $val, Dec => $val
    );
    array_push($arrayName, $datos);
  } 
  else{

  }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en el `else` busque el `cliente` y reemplace un valor **de enero a de diciembre**?

Comment: Has probado [`array_search()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php) ? Si no te ha servido, por favor pon la estructura de tu array de registros